# Why TRACE() throws Floating-point underflow exception?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, mfc

Why do I get a Floating-point underflow (parameters: 0x00000000) in TRACE?
What format specifier do I need here?

```
// show load progress by callback-Funktion (on Statusbar)
ULONGLONG len =  1000;   // ar.GetFile()->GetLength();
ULONGLONG pos =  800;    // ar.GetFile()->GetPosition();
double perc = (double)pos/(double)len*100; 

TRACE("load from %X, Position: %ld, Length: %ld, Perc: %lf \n", 
    this, pos, len, perc );
```

## Update

The `len` and `pos` does not care, `TRACE` throws always an Error in **Debug-Mode**.
Compiled with *Use Multi-Byte Character Set*. Upgraded the code from VS9 to VS14. In **Release-Mode** it seems working all fine.

Debug Output is:

```
Natvis: Parsing natvis xml file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\windows.media.natvis.
Natvis: Parsing natvis xml file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\windows.natvis.
Natvis: Parsing natvis xml file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\winrt.natvis.
Natvis: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\atlmfc.natvis(9,28): Successfully parsed expression 'm_hWnd' in type context 'CWnd'.
Exception thrown at 0x5B4EE469 (ucrtbased.dll) in TestProgD.exe: 0xC0000093: Floating-point underflow (parameters: 0x00000000).
Unhandled exception at 0x5B4EE469 (ucrtbased.dll) TestProgD.exe: 0xC0000093: Floating-point underflow (parameters: 0x00000000).
```

Comment: Please show the verbatim output you get and also show the actual values of `len` and `pos`.

Comment: Have you tried building it with code analysis to see what it brings to your attention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format specifiers do not match the argument types, so you have undefined behaviour.

- `%X` (`unsigned int`) should be `%p` (pointer).
- `%ld` (`long int`) should be `%llu` (`unsigned long long`). On the Windows platform `long int` is the same as `int`, so it is always 32-bit, regardless whether the code is built for 32-bit or 64-bit. Only `long long` is always 64-bit. Of course you also want to match the signedness, that's why the `u` specifier must be used.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx).

Comment: Cool. I think that code analysis will pick up on these issues. It does for me.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I've enabled "all microsoft rules" in project settings > code analysis but I don't receive any warning.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle When I replace `TRACE` by `printf` I do get the expected warnings though. I also get warnings for `CString::Format()`.

Comment: Yes, I had to use a cast of `LPCTSTR` for all `CString` parameters to `%s` format specifiers. I would have thought that `TRACE` behaved like `printf`. Oh well!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle [Follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48733619/7571258).

Comment: I'm not sure, why the code produces a floating point error, though. The final specifier (`%lf`) should be used with `long double`. While a `long double` has the same memory layout as a `double` with Microsoft's compiler, that shouldn't matter. Although the correct specifier would be `%f`.

Comment: @IInspectable In my test I didn't get a floating point error but the value printed out as `0`. I believe that half of the bits of the `len` argument get interpreted for the last argument in the same way as `TRACE("%d,%d\n", POINT{1,2});` prints out both members of the `POINT` structure.

Comment: Thx. Yes this corrected Format-Parameter has solved the issue. My examination, why I got the floating-point error, is because a library set the floationg-point control word with _controlfp(~(EM_OVERFLOW | EM_UNDERFLOW | EM_DENORMAL), MCW_EM);  Attention: 0 = set the exception, 1 = clearing the exception.