# How to enable warnings for incorrect use of TRACE / ATLTRACE

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2017, compiler-warnings

The following MFC program (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48705742/7571258)) has obvious errors as the format specifiers do not match the actual argument types:

```
#include <afx.h>

int main()
{
    int const a = 0;
    ULONGLONG const len = 1000;
    ULONGLONG const pos = 800;
    double const perc = static_cast<double>( pos ) / static_cast<double>( len * 100 ); 

    TRACE( "load from %X, Position: %ld, Length: %ld, Perc: %lf \n", 
           &a, pos, len, perc ); 
}
```

Yet, there are no compiler warnings. I have build this in debug configuration with warning level 4. Code analysis also doesn't raise anything.

There are warnings when `TRACE` is replaced by `printf`:

```
printf("load from %X, Position: %ld, Length: %ld, Perc: %lf \n", 
       &a, pos, len, perc );
```

Compiler warnings (duplicates omitted):

```
warning C4477: "printf": The format string "% X" requires an argument of type "unsigned int", but the variadic argument "1" has the type "int *".
warning C4477: "printf": The format string "% ld" requires an argument of type "long", but the variadic argument "2" has the type "ULONGLONG".
note: If necessary, use% lld in the format string.
note: If necessary, use "% I64d" in the format string.
warning C6273: A non-integer was passed as _Param_ (2). However, calling "printf" requires an integer. Actual type: "int *". If a pointer value is passed,% p should be used.
warning C6328: Size Conflict: "unsigned __int64" was passed as _Param_ (3). However, calling "printf" requires "int".
warning C6340: Sign conflict: "unsigned __int64" is passed as _Param_ (3) if a signed type is required in the call to "printf".
```

Replacing `TRACE` by `CString::Format()` does not produce compiler warnings, but enabling code analysis produces similar warnings.

Is it possible to produce such warnings (either compiler warnings or code analysis warnings) for incorrect use of the `TRACE` / `ATLTRACE` macros in existing code?

Comment: `CString::Format` has a similar problem, which probably has to do with the variable argument getting passed to another function. It doesn't get any compiler warnings, but Code Analysis does show the expected report for `CString::Format`. Maybe VS treats `CString::Format` differently than other functions!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I had tested `CString::Format()` aswell so I propably assumed the `printf` warnings came from code analysis. I've edited the question accordingly. The basic question remains though.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler checks are function specific and cannot be enabled for other functions, e.g. by SAL annotations. However, it's possible to redefine tracing macros like this: "if(1) { <real trace> } else { printf(<same arguments>); }". In this case the compiler still jumps in with its argument checks.

Comment: [Format Specifiers Checker](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/06/22/format-specifiers-checking/) was introduced in VS 2015, but is only done for a predefined set of CRT functions. A few workarounds to get it for user-defined functions are mentioned in the comments.